# Spacer cause overflow issue

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I have two texts in a row, and one of them is way longer than the other one. I use spacer to give more spaces to one of the texts. If the text gets really long, it causes an overflow. How do I fix this?

```
title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Spacer(),
          Text(
            "Longer text",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(
                  color:
                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.white.withOpacity(0.85),
                ),
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            softWrap: false,
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text(
            "smaller text",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(
                  color:
                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.white.withOpacity(0.85),
                ),
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            softWrap: false,
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
          Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as _text_ rather then an image.

Comment: Try adding: 'mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min' to the row

Answer (score 0):

wrap the text widget with the Expanded widget and give them spacing whatever you want

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,// if you give them 1 flex value to Expanded widget both they take equal space and if you give one widget 2 flex value and one 1 flex value the one with 2 flex value will get double the space of the other 
  child:Text("Longer text")
)
```

Comment: I don't want this. I want the longer text to take the space of the smaller one if needed, if they are equal, no need to take extra space.  with spacer everything is great except I need to prevent from overflow issue

Comment: then just wrap the long text with expanded and remove the spacer the long text will take all the space remaining

Comment: now they're not the center anymore.

Comment: try adding textAlign: TextAlign.center property to text.

Comment: It didn't work! Now bigger text is center, then huge space, then smaller text

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RichText` like this:

```
Center(
    child: RichText(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'smaller text',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.85),
        ),
        children: [TextSpan(text: 'Longer text ')],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want them to be centered in case the longer text is the same size as the smaller text.  In your case, it's not the center (First picture).

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out @sina.s

Comment: @sina.s was it what you want?